# Clean Project "Command builtin-rm failed with exit code 513" found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have try to clean my project but showing error **"Command builtin-rm failed with exit code 513"**

I have attached screen shot of error msg:[image]

Thank You

Comment: try alt + cmd+ shift + k

Comment: @maku I have already try..

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: @MikeOnorato  I am using xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error in Xcode 9.2. Upgrading to High Sierra and Xcode 9.3 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with Xcode 9.2 and fixed by deleting all the files from the DerivedData folder. Also, Delete/Empty from Trash.

1. Quit the Xcode.
2. Go to Xcode DerivedData Folder and delete all the files.

   XCode -> Preferences -> Locations -> DerivedData
3. Delete from Trash also.
4. Launch the Xcode again and check.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error for my macOS app.

If you are developing apps for the Mac App Store, the generated receipt file (`MyApp.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt`) will be owned by root. Hence Xcode won't be able to remove it.

Apple should make developing apps for the Mac App Store easier in general.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the files in product target folder will resolve this issue.